# Modeling rate data using Poisson regression using glm2()

Tags: r

I would like to analyze rate data using Poisson regression. So, my outcome is the number of cases over a period of time or area. The offset then is the number of person-years or census tracts. When using `glm()` or `glm2()`, do I model the offset on the logarithmic scale? Does it matter if I use the `offset()` in the `formula` argument of `glm()` as compared to using the `offset()` argument?

In other words, are

```
## Including offset(log(n)) in the right hand side
model.1 <- glm(cases ~ city + age.range + offset(log(n)), family = poisson(link = "log"), data = nonmel)

## And using the offset option
model.1 <- glm(cases ~ city + age.range, offset = log(n), family = poisson(link = "log"), data = nonmel)
```

equivalent?

Answer (score 0):

[Yes, they are equivalent](https://rpubs.com/kaz_yos/poisson). You can either use the `offset` argument or write it in the formula using the `offset()` function in the **stats** package. Note that the logarithm is not taken, so with regular populations, areas, or times, the offsets need to under a logarithmic transformation. So use

```r
offset(log(n)) 
#or
offset = log(n)
```

in the `glm()` and `glm2()` functions.